# awk: match pattern and print lines after and before till next pattern

Tags: awk

Using awk:
Find a pattern.
Print all lines after that pattern till next pattern.
Print all lines before that pattern till next pattern.

eg. if this is the content of the file

```
?hello@
line-0
?type=A;so on
line-1
short-description
line-2
line-3
ending@
line-4
?bye@
```

match pattern `short-description` and print lines after till pattern `@` and print lines before till pattern `?` so the output should be:

```
?type=A;so on
line-1
short-description
line-2
line-3
ending@
```

i tried: awk '/short-description/{copy=1;next} /@/{copy=0;next} copy' file

but i don't know how to get the before pattern part, i have very limited knowledge of awk. Also please provide a one line solution.

please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: what have  you tried? Good luck.

Comment: awk '/short-description/{copy=1;next} /@/{copy=0;next} copy' file

Comment: but i don't know how to get it for before the pattern

Comment: Edit the question to add what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
/^\?/ { delete arr ; len = 0 ; hit = 0 }
/^\?/,/@$/ {
    arr[len++] = $0
    if ( /short-description/ )
      hit = 1
}
/@$/ {
    if(hit)
      for(i=0;i<len;++i)
        print arr[i]
}
```

Or, this one-liner:

```
BEGIN { RS="?" } /short-description/ { sub("@.*","") ; print $0 }
```

Comment: can you please provide a one liner solution. I'm sorry I don't have much knowledge of awk.

Comment: ok i tried: awk BEGIN { RS="?" } /short-description/ { sub("@.*","") ; print $0 } file . . . but it gave me this error: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: If you are not doing so already, you will have to enclose the whole awk script with single-quotes, to pass the script into awk as a single command-line parameter.  Then, each file to process is another parameter to awk.

Comment: yeah i tried that too but it just prints the whole file: awk 'BEGIN { RS="?" } /short-description/ { sub("@.*","") ; print $0 }' FileName.xml

Comment: Hrm, not sure then what is the problem.  Can you perhaps replace `awk` with `nawk` or `gawk`?  It looks like you are using `bash`, so single quotes should be fine.